# "Error compiling Cython file " when I want to convert py to apk

Tags: python, kivy, google-colaboratory

I tried every thing to convert my app to apk madule but nothing worked for me
and this error is the newest error I get at colab and linux bouth
please help me for that

```
    Error compiling Cython file:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ...
        if self.appsink != NULL:
            gst_element_get_state(self.pipeline, &current_state,
                    &pending_state, <GstClockTime>GST_SECOND)
            if current_state != GST_STATE_PLAYING:
                c_appsink_pull_preroll(
                    self.appsink, _on_appsink_sample, <void *>self)
```

I tried any thing I found at google